# How to print and save the result to a file at the same time?

Tags: windows-server-2012, printing, queue

I'm trying to print on Windows Server 2012. It works fine, but **I'd want to generate an output file** (some kind of .PRN) **in order to save the last print job** so it can be printed again later.

Enabling a printer pool with two printer queues doesn't work, because it will choose the fastest one. Moreover, **I wouldn't want to use a third party software**, if possible.

Any ideas? Help will be apreciated.

Regards.

Comment: We've finally used a Powershell script to solve this out. Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Properties pages of the printer, on the Advanced tab, check the "keep printed documents" checkbox.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for answering, @joeqwerty. We've already thought about that solution, **but it isn't possible because every print job generates a 3 MB file**. We have twenty users, and they can print three or four jobs a minute.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a third party software, but because there has not been an approved answer I can maybe suggest using a commercial solution. 
This video shows you how to print a document and also archive and email it. Maybe you can archive it as PDF file on another (network) location or FTP so you can print the PDF files again when necessarry?

[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDQGBBUhr8Y&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=32)